# How to create PR to Upstream repo

Tags: github-actions

I have an original repo (private) in my personal account. I forked this repo with my organization account. I created a Personal Token to try access to this via API.

I need an action to create auto PR to the upstream when I merge to main branch on child repo.

I have the following action on forked repo:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Get current package version
        uses: martinbeentjes/npm-get-version-action@v1.2.3

      
           # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Pushing to client... v${{ steps.npm-get-version-action.outputs.current-version }}
        
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.API_GITHUB }}
          script: |
            const { repo, owner } = context.repo;

            const result = await github.rest.pulls.create({
              title: 'release v${{ steps.npm-get-version-action.outputs.current-version }}',
              owner,
              repo: '<<URL OF ORIGINAL REPO>>',
              head: '${{ github.ref_name }}',
              base: 'main',
            });
            
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Pushed!
```

I got at "Unhandled error: HttpError: Not Found"

how can I make a PR to upstream with this?

Comment: There are some actions on [the marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=pull+request) that can do it for you instead of using a script usin lg the Github API. Did you try one of them?

Comment: Yep @GuiFalourd, I tried some of these,  but i couldn't create a PR on forked repo :S

Comment: I found an interesting thread [here](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/issues/1003) that may give you some insights.